# Is there any complex number $a$ solving $\exp (X)=1+aX$ for given square matrix $X$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

I am doing exercises in Rossmann's book on Lie groups. Exercise 1.2.12 goes like this:

$X \in M_n (\mathbb{C})$, $L$ is a subspace of $M_n (\mathbb{C})$, s.t. $[X, Y]\in L$ for $Y\in L$. Prove that $\exp (-X)\exp (X+Y)\in 1+L $.

There is a hint that we consider derivative of $\exp (-X)\exp (X+tY)$. That is

$$\frac{I-e^{-\mathrm{ad}X}}{\mathrm{ad}X}Y,$$

which 'seems' to sit in $L$.

However, if you let $L=\mathbb{C} X$, one claims that it contradicts for $\exp (X)$ may not be expressed as $1+aX$.

My question is whether the claim is true or not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The $ 2\times 2$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1$ and $2$ is a counterexample to the statement in the title.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much. It is brief and clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to note that you incorrectly used Theorem 5 in the book.  I restate it here (with minor changes to make things clearer and less confusing).

> **Theorem 5** [section 1.2, page 15, in *[Lie Groups: An Introduction Through Linear Groups](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rossmann/Lie_book_files/Section%201-1.pdf)* by Wulf Rossman].  Let $Z:\Bbb{R}\to M_n(\Bbb{C})$ be a differentiable matrix function.  Then,
>   $$\frac{d}{d\tau}e^{Z(\tau)}=e^{Z(\tau)}\left(\frac{1-e^{-\operatorname{ad}Z(\tau)}}{\operatorname{ad}Z(\tau)}\right)\frac{d}{d\tau}Z(\tau).$$
>   Here, $$\left(\frac{1-e^{-\operatorname{ad}Z(\tau)}}{\operatorname{ad}Z(\tau)}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}\big(\operatorname{ad}Z(\tau)\big)^k.$$

Let's look at your counter-example.  I will illustrate here how to correctly apply the theorem above.  For $L=\Bbb{C}X$, we set, WLOG, $Y=X$.  So, 
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}e^{-X}e^{X+tY}&=e^{-X}e^{X+tY}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}\big(\operatorname{ad}X+t\operatorname{ad}Y\big)^k\right)Y\\&=e^{-X}e^{(1+t)X}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(1+t)^k}{(k+1)!}(\operatorname{ad}X)^k\right)X
\\&=e^{-X}e^{(1+t)X}X=Xe^{tX}.\end{align}
That is, for $L=\Bbb C X$ and $Y=X$,
$$e^{-X}e^{X+tY}=e^{tX}.$$
In particular, $e^{-X}e^{X+Y}=e^X=e^Y$ when $Y=X$.  This is not in the form $I+aX$ in general just as Kavi Rama Murthy's comment shows, unless we have a stronger condition on $L$ such as $L$ is closed under left multiplication by any element of $\tilde{L}=L+\mathbb{C}X$.

In the section below, I verify that the assumption that $L$ is a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with the properties that $[X,T]\in L$ for all $T\in L$ and that $L$ is closed under left multiplication by $X$ and elements of $L$ itself, then the claim holds.  Without this extra assumption, we already see that the problem is wrong.

---

> **Modified Problem Statement.**  Fix $X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$.  Let $L$ be a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with the properties that $[X,T]\in L$ for all $T\in L$, and that $L$ is closed under left multiplication by any element of $\tilde{L}=L+\mathbb{C}X$, then $$e^{-X}e^{X+Y}\in I+L$$ for all $Y\in L$.

From the theorem, you should take $Z(t)=X+tY$.  That is,
$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{-X}e^{X+tY}=e^{-X}\frac{d}{dt}e^{Z(t)}=e^{-X}\Biggl(e^{Z(t)}\left(\frac{1-e^{-\operatorname{ad}Z(t)}}{\operatorname{ad}Z(t)}\right)\frac{d}{dt}Z(t)\Biggr).$$
Since $\frac{d}{dt}Z(t)=Y$, we get
$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{-X}e^{X+tY}=e^{-X}e^{X+tY}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}\big(\operatorname{ad}X+t\operatorname{ad}Y\big)^k\right)Y.$$
Because $\operatorname{ad}X(Y)=[X,Y]\in L$ and $\operatorname{ad}Y(Y)=[Y,Y]=0\in L$, we obtain $$\big(\operatorname{ad}X+t\operatorname{ad}Y\big)^kY\in L.$$  This proves that
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}\big(\operatorname{ad}X+t\operatorname{ad}Y\big)^k\right)Y \in L\,.$$  Now, because $e^{X+tY}T\in L$ for all $T\in L$ because $L$ is closed under left multiplication by any element of $\tilde{L}=L+\mathbb{C}X$, we see also that $e^{-X}e^{X+tY}T\in L$ as well.  This means
$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{-X}e^{X+tY}=e^{-X}e^{X+tY}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}\big(\operatorname{ad}X+t\operatorname{ad}Y\big)^k\right)Y\in L.$$
This proves that
$$e^{-X}e^{X+\tau Y}-I=\int_0^\tau\frac{d}{dt}e^{-X}e^{X+tY}\ dt \in L,$$
and the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed calculation. But I am most doubtful whether we can claim that a formal series is in L with each term in L. In arbitrary vector space it might not allowed to sum up infinite vectors. And what's your opinion to Murthy's comment above? I thought it is solid.

Comment: Sorry I have checked it again. Say in your notation $Z'(t)=Z(t)v(t)$. You proved $v\in L$. How to show that $Zv$ is still in $L$?

Comment: I don't have any $v$ in my notation.  What is $v$?  Is it $Y$?  But then $Y$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: My fault. I mean $\frac{d}{dt}e^{-X}e^{X+tY}=e^{-X}e^{X+tY}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}\big(\operatorname{ad}X+t\operatorname{ad}Y\big)^k\right)Y$. The infinite sum is in $L$. There is an $e^{X+tY}$ in the formula. For $t=0$ it is fine. How about general $t$?

Comment: Think of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a normed space given by the Frobenius norm or something.  Then, note that $L$ is a closed subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.  Show that $Y_n(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}(\operatorname{ad}{X}+t\operatorname{ad}{Y})^kY$ form a convergent sequence for each $t$.  Since $L$ is closed, each $Y_n(t)$ is in $L$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n(t)$ exists, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n(t)$ is in $L$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am okay with the fact that the sum is in $L$. But my question is that, just on the left of the sum, there is an $e^{-X}e^{X+tY}$, which is not identity when $t\ne 0$. How to show that it keeps the sum in $L$?

Comment: @KirbyLee  You got me realize that I made a faulty assumption all along.  I assumed that $L$ is a left ideal of the matrix ring $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ by mistake.  There is no such assumption in the problem statement.  And in fact, without this assumption or something similar, the problem is wrong, and you are very right to doubt the problem's correctness.  I am sorry about this.